# My android app is crashing on different devices

Tags: android, eclipse, crash, manifest, device

I've tested my application on my phone(LG Optimus NET) and Galaxy Mini and everything is working fine. But when I want to test it on bigger screen devices, it gives crash at start. I tried on S3 and AllView(i don't really know the model).

My manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.swipefragments"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
    <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true" android:smallScreens="true"
        android:resizeable="true" android:anyDensity="true" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Sherlock" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.swipefragments.MainActivity"
            android:label="Stiai ca..." 
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity {
    static final int NUM_ITEMS = 550;

    MyAdapter mAdapter;

    ViewPager mPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_pager);

        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Watch for button clicks.
        Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.goto_first);
//        button.getBackground().setColorFilter(0xFF0174DF, PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mPager.setCurrentItem(0);
            }
        });
        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.goto_last);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 mPager.setCurrentItem(NUM_ITEMS-1);
            }
        });

        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.goto_random);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Random r = new Random();
                int i1=r.nextInt(529)+20;
                mPager.setCurrentItem(i1);
            }
        });

        button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.goto_about);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {

             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ciuboariu Florin, Ianuarie 2013", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
    }

    public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_ITEMS;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return ArrayListFragment.newInstance(position);
        }
    }

    public static class ArrayListFragment extends SherlockListFragment {
        int mNum;

        /**
         * Create a new instance of CountingFragment, providing "num"
         * as an argument.
         */
        static ArrayListFragment newInstance(int num) {
            ArrayListFragment f = new ArrayListFragment();

            // Supply num input as an argument.
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("num", num);
            f.setArguments(args);

            return f;
        }

        /**
         * When creating, retrieve this instance's number from its arguments.
         */
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
//            Random r = new Random();
//          int i1=r.nextInt(70-1)+1;
//            mNum = i1;
            mNum = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("num") : 1;
        }

        /**
         * The Fragment's UI is just a simple text view showing its
         * instance number.
         */
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager_list, container, false);
            View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.text2);
            switch(mNum){
            IMENSE HERE- deleted
            }
            return v;
        }



        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        }




        @Override
        public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
            Log.i("FragmentList", "Item clicked: " + id);
        }
    }
```

LogCat:

```
01-14 21:42:13.969: E/dalvikvm-heap(17739): Creating VM heap of size start:2097152 max:536870912 base:0x4000c000
01-14 21:42:14.089: E/Tethering(11125): <!>com.android.server.connectivity.Tethering 278<!> active iface (usb0) reported as added, ignoring
01-14 21:42:14.509: E/dalvikvm-heap(17750): Creating VM heap of size start:2097152 max:536870912 base:0x4000c000
01-14 21:42:14.749: I/ActivityManager(11125): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.swipefragments/.MainActivity } from pid 17750
01-14 21:42:14.769: D/LGEHome(11472): <!>com.lge.launcher.HLog 26<!> Launcher.java:1809:onPause()onPause
01-14 21:42:14.769: D/LGEHome(11472): <!>com.lge.launcher.HLog 26<!> Workspace.java:528:updateWallpaperOffset()1 firstEmptyScreen: 6
01-14 21:42:14.769: D/LGEHome(11472): <!>com.lge.launcher.HLog 26<!> Workspace.java:529:updateWallpaperOffset()1 getChildAt(firstEmptyScreen).getRight() 2240
01-14 21:42:14.769: D/LGEHome(11472): <!>com.lge.launcher.HLog 26<!> Workspace.java:536:updateWallpaperOffset()2 scrollRange: 1920, firstEmptyScreen: 6
01-14 21:42:14.779: D/LGEHome(11472): <!>com.lge.launcher.HLog 26<!> Workspace.java:542:updateWallpaperOffset()2 mCurDesktopState: 0, firstEmptyScreen: 6
01-14 21:42:14.779: D/LGEHome(11472): <!>com.lge.launcher.HLog 26<!> Workspace.java:547:updateWallpaperOffset()3 getScrollX: 960, mScrollX: 960
01-14 21:42:14.779: D/LGEHome(11472): <!>com.lge.launcher.HLog 26<!> Workspace.java:548:updateWallpaperOffset()3 getChildAt(firstEmptyScreen).getLeft(): 1920
01-14 21:42:14.779: D/LGEHome(11472): <!>com.lge.launcher.HLog 26<!> Workspace.java:554:updateWallpaperOffset()4 xOffset: 0.5
01-14 21:42:14.859: D/LGEHome(11472): <!>com.lge.launcher.HLog 26<!> Workspace.java:528:updateWallpaperOffset()1 firstEmptyScreen: 6
01-14 21:42:14.929: D/LGEHome(11472): <!>com.lge.launcher.HLog 26<!> Workspace.java:529:updateWallpaperOffset()1 getChildAt(firstEmptyScreen).getRight() 2240
01-14 21:42:14.929: D/LGEHome(11472): <!>com.lge.launcher.HLog 26<!> Workspace.java:536:updateWallpaperOffset()2 scrollRange: 1920, firstEmptyScreen: 6
01-14 21:42:14.929: D/LGEHome(11472): <!>com.lge.launcher.HLog 26<!> Workspace.java:542:updateWallpaperOffset()2 mCurDesktopState: 0, firstEmptyScreen: 6
01-14 21:42:14.929: D/LGEHome(11472): <!>com.lge.launcher.HLog 26<!> Workspace.java:547:updateWallpaperOffset()3 getScrollX: 960, mScrollX: 960
01-14 21:42:14.939: D/LGEHome(11472): <!>com.lge.launcher.HLog 26<!> Workspace.java:548:updateWallpaperOffset()3 getChildAt(firstEmptyScreen).getLeft(): 1920
01-14 21:42:14.959: I/#LGIME(11205): <!>com.jungle.android.utils.Glog 35<!> ### onFinishInput
01-14 21:42:14.959: I/#LGIME(11205): <!>com.jungle.android.utils.Glog 35<!> #### onStartInput restarting : false / inputType : 0
01-14 21:42:14.959: I/Flex(11205): <!>com.lge.provider.Andy_Flex 186<!> getMccCode numeric 22610
01-14 21:42:14.969: I/Flex(11205): <!>com.lge.provider.Andy_Flex 218<!> getMncCode numeric 22610
01-14 21:42:14.969: I/#LGIME(11205): <!>com.jungle.android.utils.Glog 35<!> updateSIMInfo -> Old MCC : 226,Old MNC : 3 MCC = 226 MNC = 10
01-14 21:42:14.999: D/LGEHome(11472): <!>com.lge.launcher.HLog 26<!> Workspace.java:554:updateWallpaperOffset()4 xOffset: 0.5
01-14 21:42:15.139: I/ActivityManager(11125): <!>com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord 444<!> Displayed com.example.swipefragments/.MainActivity: +329ms
01-14 21:42:16.119: E/Tethering(11125): <!>com.android.server.connectivity.Tethering 278<!> active iface (usb0) reported as added, ignoring
01-14 21:42:18.759: D/StatusBarPolicy(11197): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 8
01-14 21:42:18.759: D/StatusBarPolicy(11197): [BRIGHTHY] curNetwork=22610 curHPLMN=22610
01-14 21:42:18.759: D/StatusBarPolicy(11197): [BRIGHTHY]  getNationalRoaming=false Roaming=false
01-14 21:42:20.109: E/Tethering(11125): <!>com.android.server.connectivity.Tethering 278<!> active iface (usb0) reported as added, ignoring
01-14 21:42:22.109: E/Tethering(11125): <!>com.android.server.connectivity.Tethering 278<!> active iface (usb0) reported as added, ignoring
01-14 21:42:24.099: E/Tethering(11125): <!>com.android.server.connectivity.Tethering 278<!> active iface (usb0) reported as added, ignoring
01-14 21:42:30.759: D/StatusBarPolicy(11197): [BRIGHTHY] 0. mDataNetType: 8
01-14 21:42:30.759: D/StatusBarPolicy(11197): [BRIGHTHY] curNetwork=22610 curHPLMN=22610
01-14 21:42:30.759: D/StatusBarPolicy(11197): [BRIGHTHY]  getNationalRoaming=false Roaming=false
01-14 21:42:30.829: V/DATA(11214): <!>com.android.internal.telephony.MMDataConnectionTracker 1820<!> [DCT] intent received :android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF
01-14 21:42:30.839: V/FASTDORMANCTY(11214): <!>com.android.internal.telephony.LgeFastDormancyHandler 987<!> [UNKNOWN] intent received :android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF
01-14 21:42:35.799: D/[Andy_Lock](11125): <!>com.android.internal.policy.impl.Andy_LockScreen 1556<!>  getCurrentStatus simStateREADY
01-14 21:42:35.869: I/#LGIME(11205): <!>com.jungle.android.utils.Glog 35<!> Action : android.intent.action.CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS
01-14 21:42:35.879: E/WindowManager(11125): <!>com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindowManager 2211<!> bwk  rotationForOrientationLw case return
```

Thank you.

Comment: Need to see your logcat.

Comment: That logcat doesn't show any crash.

Comment: @Falmarri Because on my device is working fine, but on my friend's device it crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In what folders are placed the following layouts?

- R.layout.fragment_pager
- R.layout.fragment_pager_list

In layout or in layout-*??

**EDIT:**

I think the problem is in this code (related to `SherlockFragmentActivity`:

```
getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
            WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Try using xml instead (add it in the activity in manifest file):

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.example.swipefragments.MainActivity"
        android:label="Stiai ca..." 
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Hope it helps!
If it does, you know what to do ;)

Cheers!

Comment: It is placed in res/layout.

Comment: by the way, the logcat is not relevant to what you're saying... there is no relevant error there... and can't understant the reason of application crash.

Comment: Yea, the app is working fine on my device. But it crashes on other devices.

Comment: Log-ul pe care l-ai scris nu contine nici o eroare in el... incearca si pune un log in care se contine si eroarea in cauza, altfel nush de ce crapa...

Comment: putem vorbi si in romana? Cum sa fac sa primesc eroare...? Sa imprumut telefonul unui coleg sa incerc sa dau build cu el in eclipse?

Comment: desigur, doar adminii sa nu zica ceva

Comment: N-am nici o idee de ce nu functioneaza. Pe telefoanele cu aceeasi rezolutie ca a mea, tot e perfect. Poate e din cauza versiunii de android pe care le au device-urile?

Comment: pai la acel care crapa are versiune mai veche?

Comment: Din contra, la versiunea 2.3 nu e nici o problema. La v4 crapa.

Comment: I commented       requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);       getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
               WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
      getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
      getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);     and now it works! Thank you. (MERSI MULT DE TOT!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!)

Answer (score 0):

It is almost impossible to say without seeing any code or logs, but I'll give a couple ideas.

I see "swipefragments" in your package name. Are you using fragments in your layout? If so, implementing them incorrectly may cause it to crash only on large screen devices, since fragments are handled differently on smaller screen devices.

Also, I had a similar problem that turned out to be that I was accessing files in a non-generic way (looking in specific locations) and it worked on most devices but crashed on those that implemented their file system differently.

If you provide at least code for `MainActivity`, it will be much easier to say with any accuracy....